# Use Adobe Audition to Remove Vocals

Tags: vocals, removal

I am entirely new to audio editing, and one of the things I am trying to do is remove vocals from a song. I have tried using the center channel extractor to do this, but it has not worked properly. How would I go about doing this?

Here is the song that I am trying to remove the vocals from:

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be easy, the vocal is all over the stereo-field so using a centre-channel extractor unsurprisingly didn't work well.

Except if the vocal track is fairly unprocessed and clean, its actually very difficult to remove it from the recording.

You could try using a spectral editor like iZotope RX, and remove it manually, or some clever automation with EQ or even perhaps a multi-band compressor.

It's usually less hassle to try to get the authors to send you the instrumental mix.

edit: I forgot, Audition has a built-in spectral editor (albeit less powerful than RX), so you could try with that.

Comment: Automation with EQ? What is that?

Comment: I just got an idea, although I do not know how useful it is. Would using the Invert feature in Audacity move it to the center field so I could extract it with Adobe Audition?